# Any ideas why this Pinescript is repainting in real-time (have used "barstate.confirmed" on "request.security" but it doesn't seem to be helping)?

Tags: pine-script, pine-script-v5

I am aware using "request.security" can be associated with repainting. I am retrieving data from another symbol on the same timeframe as the chart with the "timeframe.period" argument in "request.security".

The problem I have is that when running the script in real-time I often get signals that disappear later (repainting).

I have incorporated the "barstate.isconfirmed" condition to be true to try to avoid this (see script) but it doesn't seem to have helped. Why might this be?

```
//@version=5
strategy(title="Triangular arbitrage-based information (Q) strategy", overlay=false, default_qty_type = strategy.cash, default_qty_value = 100000, initial_capital = 100000, currency = currency.GBP, slippage = 5)

i_from = input.time(defval = timestamp("1 November 2023 00:00 +0000"), title = "From")
i_to = input.time(defval = timestamp("1 February 2024 00:00 +0000"), title = "To")

date() => time >= i_from and time <= i_to

//Define variables
src = input(defval=close, title="Source")
H_length = input.int(1, title="H length")
rank_lookback = input.int(defval=2000, title= "p_i percentage rank lookback", step=1)
Q_lookback = input.int(defval=2000, title="Q percentage rank lookback", step=1)
Q_sig = input.float(defval=3, title="Q percentage rank significance level", step=0.1)
MA_length = input.int(20,minval=1)
exp = input(true, "Use Exponential MA")
esma(source, length)=>
    s = ta.sma(source, length)
    e = ta.ema(source, length)
    exp ? e : s
ma = esma(src, MA_length)
plot(ma, color=color.white)

instrument01 = request.security(input(defval="FX_IDC:GBPUSD", title="Instrument01"),timeframe.period, expression = src)
instrument02 = request.security(input(defval="FX_IDC:GBPJPY", title="Instrument02 (carry)"),timeframe.period, expression = src)
instrument03 = request.security(input(defval="FX_IDC:JPYUSD", title="Instrument03"),timeframe.period, expression = src)

//Detect triangular arbitrage opportunities
Triarbcond = instrument01-(instrument02*instrument03)
Triarbmod = math.abs(Triarbcond)

//Percentage ranking
p_1 = (100-ta.percentrank(Triarbmod, rank_lookback))/100
p_2 = ta.percentrank(Triarbmod, rank_lookback)/100
plot(p_1, title="p_1", color=color.fuchsia, style=plot.style_histogram)
v = p_1 * math.log(p_1) + p_2 * math.log(p_2)
Q = -math.log(p_1)
H = -math.sum(v, H_length)
plot(Q, title= "Information", color=color.lime, style=plot.style_histogram)
plot(H, title= "H", color=color.rgb(0, 230, 230), style=plot.style_histogram)

//Mark statistical outliers in Q
Q_rank = ta.percentrank(Q, Q_lookback)
short = Q_rank > (100 - Q_sig)? true: na
long = Q_rank < Q_sig? true: na
plotshape(short? Q : na, location=location.absolute, style=shape.triangledown, color=color.new(color.red, 30), size=size.tiny, offset=0)
plotshape(long? Q : na, location=location.absolute, style=shape.triangleup, color=color.new(color.green, 30), size=size.tiny, offset=0)

//Define entry and exit conditions
if date() and close>ma and short
    strategy.entry("Short",strategy.short, comment="Short")
if date() and close<ma and short
    strategy.entry("Long",strategy.long, comment="Long")
```